# Substitute to Madi Clothes

Tags: scripture

For those who don’t know, Madi clothes are clothes which are washed after which it is left untouched, thus making it pure. The cloth material can be touched next, only by the person who is going to wear it, after taking a head bath.

This is practised on religious occasions and festivities to maintain the purity of the cloth.

For those who are not able to obtain Madi clothes due to some reason such as travel, is there any substitute to Madi clothes, or can non-Madi clothes be made just as pure as Madi clothes by following some other method?

[PS: I couldn’t find any relevant tag, so I have just tagged scripture.]

Comment: Thavadai or woolen vashtras are madi you dont need to wash and keep offcourse you can wash them occasionaly, Any deer skin is madi but its banned in india..

Comment: @PrasannaR Sorry but what is Thavadai?

Comment: you can wear slik clothes because its not from thread its made of slik scretion its madi only..

Comment: thavadai is karanataka is woolen vashtra.. sheep hair

Comment: @PrasannaR Can you also answer the second part of my question which asks for other methods to make non-Madi clothes as pure as Madi clothes? For example, wet clothes can be made Madi by showing them to the Sun, and spinning them seven times. Are there any such methods to make normal clothes pure?

Comment: yes offsourse people do pooja and sharada with wet clothes.. i personally feel that wet clothes should be dried and worn otherwise there will be contamination from clothes you can get sticky with mud or whatever environment you are surrounded..